# BinaryWriter not writing to file

Tags: c#, io, binaryfiles

I am trying to write data files to disk so that I can cache large amounts of data that won't fit into memory. In some early tests I find that sometimes I get data written and sometimes not. Here is a sample that shows the process not working:

```
using System.IO;
using System;


namespace TestBinaryWriter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            double dFoo = 1234.1234;
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("asdf"));
            bw.Write(dFoo);
            bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(dFoo));
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of file 'asdf' are empty and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5):

Initialize and use `BinaryWriter` in using block:

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("asdf"))
{
    bw.Write(dFoo);
    bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(dFoo));
}
```

What was wrong with your implementation was that the Stream was not closed (by calling close method) and contents were not properly flushed into the file.

With the `using` statement, it will automatically cause the Dispose method to be called. In the Dispose implementation, Close is called. This is how it works.

Comment: Could you additionally add *why* this solves the problem OP is having?

Comment: I think the explanation is pretty clear, now. The using statement causes Dispose to be called which closes the file that the writer is writing to. Awesome.

Answer (score 4):

`BinaryWriter` *caches* the data, to *write* data to the file yous should either do it explicitly

```
  ...
  bw.Write(dFoo);
  bw.Flush(); // <- write all the data (dFoo) down
  ...
```

or `Close` (`Dispose`) the writer. Typical pattern is `using`:

```
{
  ...

  // bw will be closed on leaving its scope  
  using BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("asdf"));

  bw.Write(dFoo);
  bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(dFoo));
  ...
} // bw will be closed here (with all data cached being written)
```

Or

```
  using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("asdf"))) {
    bw.Write(dFoo);
    bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(dFoo)); 
  } // bw will be closed here (with all data cached being written)
```

Comment: perhaps a bit pedantic, but it is probably clearer to describe as a "buffer" rather than a "cache"

Comment: It seems like in the case when one is caching large amounts of data to disk because it is too much to hold in memory that flushing periodically is necessary anyway.

Comment: @dmedine: you don't have to `Flush`: when buffer (cache) is full, writer will write it down

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing the declaration and usage of the bw variable in a using statement so that it is automatically disposed (and therefore flushed) before exiting the program.